# Using sequences convergence definition. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

The definition for convergence : The sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $L$ where $L\in \mathbb{R}$ provided that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $K$ such that for all $n\geq K$, the terms $x_n$ satisfy $|x_n-L| < \epsilon$

This is how I prove it.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, then $1/\epsilon > 0$. By the Archimedean Property, there is a natural number $K$ such that $1/K < \epsilon$. Then, if $n\geq K$, we have $1/n \leq 1/K < \epsilon$.
Note that if $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then
$1/3^n < 1/n$

Consequently, if $n\geq K$, then
$|1/3^n-0|=1/3^n<1/n<\epsilon$

Therefore, we can assert that the sequence $1/3^n$ converges to $0$

Is this right?

Comment: The proof is generally correct, but the most important point is, that you accept the inequality $3^n>n$, although it is precisely this, that creates the proof. You don’t need to prove it?

Comment: thank you. No, I don't think the question means to make us prove that

Comment: Hint: you can find such a $K$ using logarithims

Comment: No, I do not think it necessary to prove $3^n > n$ for this proof, any more than you would be expected to also prove the Archimedean property, or that $n \ge K$ implies $\frac 1n \le \frac 1K$. It is part of the background knowledge you expect the reader to already know. If someone does question it, the simple inductive proof $n+1 < n +2n = 3n < 3\cdot 3^n = 3^{n+1}$ is sufficient.